# C# NullReferenceException SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder in Sharepoint custom webpart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

So I'm trying to employ the solution found  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff519529(v=office.14).aspx#odc_office2010_DocumentAssemblyinSharePoint2010_CreateWebPartwithAssembleDocumentsCommand)

In the OnButtonCLick; the very first line throws an error:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
...on this line:
 SPFolder folder = SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder;

Here is the top few lines of the proc:

```
void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
   **SPFolder folder = SPContext.Current.ListItem.Folder;**
   char[] splitter = { '/' }; 
   string[] folderName = folder.Name.Split(splitter); 
   string filePrefix = @"Stock Analysis Demo/" + folderName[0] + "/" + folderName[0];
```

I'm quite certain that there IS a current item (I've made sure to select an item prior to hitting the button created herein & executing.

The end game here is to grab all the Word Docs in the current doc set (well, in teh current folder because the Foundation instance for development doesn't use doc sets, so I have a folder w/ docs in it for development purposes) and merge them.

Can someone explain how to remedy this being null?  My intention is to limp through this using breakpoints and get it to do what I need.

Comment: You really should debug your code and figure out what exactly is null... There is a good chance that you are not passing ID in the Url and as result `ListItem` is `null` despite you saying otherwise.

Comment: Well, I'm in debug, it's underlined the entire line, and the semi-colon is red-underlined.   Care to expound on how to dig further into the line ?

Comment: Immediate window/watch window/just simple hover over variables...

Comment: Yep, I've been usin that Immediate window.  And I can tell you that the SPContext.Current.ListItem is null.  I have this button on a custom webpart that's in the Shared Documents library. In that library there's a folder and a document.  I've check the document's select box.  So where is this SPContext lookin if not in the library where its loaded and where a listitem is selected?

Comment: See my original comment: There is a good chance that you are not passing ID in the Url and as result ListItem is null despite you saying otherwise.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't "see" where there's an "ID" in the URL, and where it'd be passed to (or from).....what do I need to post so you can tell me where this occurs?

Comment: If url does not have `?ID=1234` than `ListItem ` will be null. I have no idea how you construct Url, so I can't help you much... sorry.